# Chef: How to add changes made via dashboard to Git?

Tags: git, chef-infra

We are currently setting up opscode chef and we want to manage all cookbooks, environments etc. via Git. Is there a best practice/automatism to make sure that all changes (e.g. new Environments) that have been made via the dashboard are automatically add to version control?

Comment: This is a good question for which I don't think there is a consensus on how to address it.

Comment: Are you working with Hosted Chef? Or do you have your own Chef Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact issue is why I rarely use the Web client.  Instead I have a git repo, I save my JSON configuration in the repo and then use `knife` and its `from file` feature to update nodes, roles, environments and cookbooks.  It makes it way easier for me to make sure git and chef are up to date.

If you had to use the web interface, you could set up a cron job to regularly pull data through the Chef REST API and then commit any changes to your git repo.

Comment: However there is one problem with `knife node from file` - it removes all node attributes (including IP), until you run chef-client on it.

Comment: You're right.  But for my version control purposes, it's not that big a limitation.

Answer (score 1):

The solution we've designed (but for sake of full disclosure have not gone beyond a POC on) is to watch the couchdb for changes (http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html) and whenever a document changes we pull it from the couchdb and check it into git.

You can either do it by having listening continuously for changes or have it scripted and just keep a pointer of the last record you updated. This means the solution is completely agnostic to the client which updates the document in couchdb (ie knife/webui/recipes/command line scripts all end up registering their changes through the api and into couchdb)

Hope that's of some use to you